# Combine several excel files from multiple folders and subfolders into one pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, glob

My main folder is called "Data". Inside, I have 20 folders labelled from 1 to 20. In each of these 20 subfolders I have another 1 to 5 subfolders and one of them is called "test_results" (the one I am interested in). Inside that test_result folder I have several files, ranging from .jpeg, .csv, .xlxs. I need to work with the .xlxs files. How do I retrieve the .xlxs files ONLY that fall inside the parent folder "Data" and concatenate them into one data frame so that I can do my analyses?

I know how to do so when all the files are located in a single folder but the fact that they are in subfolders and mixed with other types of files adds complexity to it and I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#Path.glob) module.

Demo:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r'/path/to/Data')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in p.glob('**/test_results/*.xlsx')],
               ignore_index=True)
```